# SQL: How to query whether a record exists in one table based on values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
project_members:
[project_id,user_id]
1,1
1,2
2,1

employees:
[user_id]
1
2
3
```

What I need is an SQL statement that will list all project_id's which do not have all user_id's from employees within them, and the subsequent user_id's which they are missing.

So the result would read something like:

```
[project_id, user_id]
1,3
2,2
2,3
```

Because a record does not exists with project_id 1 and user_id 3 within it and so forth and so on.

Thanks for any/all help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to generate all combinations of `project_members` and `employees`. You can do that using `CROSS JOIN`. You can then use `NOT EXISTS` to get the desired result.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c24b5/1/0)

```
SELECT
    p.project_id,
    e.user_id
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT project_id FROM project_members
)p
CROSS JOIN employees e
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM project_members
        WHERE
            project_id = p.project_id
            AND user_id = e.user_id
    )
```

---

You can also use `LEFT JOIN` when checking for the existence of `project_members`:

```
SELECT
    p.project_id,
    e.user_id
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT project_id FROM project_members
)p
CROSS JOIN employees e
LEFT JOIN project_members pm
    ON pm.project_id = p.project_id
    AND pm.user_id = e.user_id
WHERE
    pm.project_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Filtering records which are not available in Project table.
SELECT a.ProjectId, b.ProjectId, b.UserId
FROM Project a
RIGHT JOIN 
(
/* Here, all the projects will be linked to all the users. So, All users will be assigned to all the projects. */
SELECT DISTINCT a.ProjectId, b.UserId
FROM Project a
CROSS JOIN Users b
) b ON a.ProjectId = b.ProjectId and a.UserId = b.UserId
WHERE a.ProjectId IS NULL
ORDER BY b.ProjectId

INNER QUERY
Project.Project_Id, Project.User_id, Employee.UserId
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
1, 1, 3
1, 2, 1
1, 2, 2
1, 2, 3
2, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
2, 1, 3

Distinct Project.Project_Id, Employee.UserId
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3

Outer query, taking records which are not available in Project table.

Please let me know for any issues
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more usable.